# Handler Ionic PWA ionBackButton

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm stuck in a problem, trying to capture when the user presses the back button when it is on the page `http://localhost/dashboard/dashboard/feed` and alert asking if user want to logout.

According to the documentation on the Ionic website, ionBackButton is not supported when the solution is PWA.

What´s the solution for handle back button for PWA, anyone can share?

[image]

I tried defining simple alert on feed.page.ts, but not working.

```
this._Platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(666666, (processNextHandler) => {
      if (window.confirm("Do you want to exit APP")) {
        alert('OK');
      }
    });
```